# setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op

Tags: reactjs

```js
componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState, prevContext) {
    let [audioNode, songLen] = [this.refs.audio, List.length-1];

    audioNode.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        this._endedPlay(songLen, () => {
            this._currSong(this.state.songIndex);
            this._Play(audioNode);
        });
    });

    audioNode.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
        let [remainTime, remainTimeMin, remainTimeSec, remainTimeInfo] = [];

        if(!isNaN(audioNode.duration)) {
            remainTime = audioNode.duration - audioNode.currentTime;
            remainTimeMin = parseInt(remainTime/60);  // 剩余分
            remainTimeSec = parseInt(remainTime%60);  // 剩余秒

            if(remainTimeSec < 10) {
                remainTimeSec = '0'+remainTimeSec;
            }
            remainTimeInfo = remainTimeMin + ':' + remainTimeSec;
            this.setState({'time': remainTimeInfo});
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount () {
    let audio = this.refs.audio;
    audio.removeEventListener('timeupdate');
    audio.removeEventListener('ended');
}
```

**Error:**

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined
>   component.

I removeEventListener 'ended' in `componentWillUnmount`, but it is not working. because I add `this.setState({'time': remainTimeInfo});` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I think this is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923656/when-route-changes-in-my-react-app-i-clearinterval-and-app-breaks/47924899#47924899

Answer (score 101):

I solved this by assigning a **ref** to the component and then checking if the ref exists before setting the state:

```
myMethod(){
  if (this.refs.myRef) 
   this.setState({myVar: true});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref="myRef">
      {this.state.myVar}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And lately, since I am using mostly functional components, I am using this pattern:

```
const Component = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setTimeout(() => { // usually fetching API data here
      if (ref.current !== null) {
        setCount((count) => count + 1);
      }
    }, 100);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={increment} ref={ref}>
      Async Increment {count}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This is very aggravating however. Pretty much all of my scenes do promise-based fetching to load, and throw this error. Why can't React just silently refuse to run setState in an unmounted state. It's not like anyone would see the difference.

Comment: This too is deprecated. But is a sweet and easy solution!

Comment: Why can't react allow setting the state since it won't matter.

Comment: Great answer. Maybe update the answer to create the `ref` using `React.createRef();` method or a callback ref ? `<div ref={(com) => this.myRef = com}>` then checking `this.myRef` instead of `this.refs.myRef`

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya this solution is deprecated?

Answer (score 23):

`removeEventListener` has the same signature as `addEventListener`. All of the arguments must be exactly the same for it to remove the listener.

```
var onEnded = () => {};
audioNode.addEventListener('ended', onEnded, false);

this.cleanup = () => {
  audioNode.removeEventListener('ended', onEnded, false);
}
```

And in componentWillUnmount call `this.cleanup()`.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue because I used `setState` instead of `state` in the constructor.

**EXAMPLE**

Change the following incorrect code

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.setState({
    key: ''
  });
}
```

to

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    key: ''
  }; 
}
```

Comment: damn i actually did this on accident just now.  thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: `isMounted` is deprecated and will probably be removed in later versions of React. See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#ismounted) and this, [isMounted is an Antipattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

---

As the warning states, you are calling `this.setState` on an a component that *was* mounted but since then has been unmounted.

To make sure your code is safe, you can wrap it in

```
if (this.isMounted()) {
    this.setState({'time': remainTimeInfo});
}
```

to ensure that the component is still mounted.

Comment: this.isMounted is deprecated and it doesn't solve the event listeners leaking (which is mostly why it's deprecated)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but why is it still used in i.e [Load Initial Data via AJAX](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) ? Where can I see the current status of it?

Comment: isMounted is an Antipattern - https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @Kolby, yes, my answer mentions that.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem since I have updated the latest react version. Solved like below.

My code was

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const { default: Component } = await importComponent();
  Nprogress.done();
  this.setState({
    component: <Component {...this.props} />
  });
}
```

Changed to

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.mounted = false;
}
async componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;
  const { default: Component } = await importComponent();
  if (this.mounted) {
    this.setState({
      component: <Component {...this.props} />
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before, and solved it according to React official page [isMounted is an Antipattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).

Set a property `isMounted` flag to be true in `componentDidMount` , and toggle it false in `componentWillUnmount`. When you `setState()` in your callbacks, check `isMounted` first! It works for me.

```
state = {
    isMounted: false
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({isMounted: true})
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
      this.setState({isMounted: false})
  }
```

callback:

```
if (this.state.isMounted) {
 this.setState({'time': remainTimeInfo});}
```

Comment: This is bad. No reason to save `isMounted` to state. You should use simply `this.isMounted`. This has nothing to do with react state.

Comment: Besides, you can't call this.setState on "componentWillUnmount": https://learn.co/lessons/react-component-mounting-and-unmounting

Comment: Maybe even `this._isMounted` so it doesn't conflict with or raise warnings from deprecated `isMounted()`, as per  the invoked official React documentation.

Comment: Actually, pending code should be cancelled in componentWillUnmount. This still is the same antipattern

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the answers in this thread get the point of using refs, but I think a complete example would be good. Since you're operating on an actual DOM node by using the event listener and stepping out of the React context, a ref should be considered the standard solution. Here's a complete example:

```
class someComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.node = null
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={node => { this.node = node }}>Content</div>
    )
  }
  handleEvent(event) {
    if (this.node) {
      this.setState({...})
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //as soon as render completes, the node will be registered.
    const handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this)
    this.node.addEventListener('click', handleEvent)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    const handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this)
    this.node.removeEventListener('click', handleEvent)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

addEventListener and removeEventListener，the Callback must not be Anonymous inner class,and they should have the same params

Comment: as @FakeRainBrigand said,since i have no reputation to comment , what i want say is 'the Callback must not be Anonymous inner class'

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that callback shouldn't be an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this warning when I wanted to show a popup (bootstrap modal) on success/failure callback of Ajax request. Additionally setState was not working and my popup modal was not being shown.

Below was my situation-

```
<Component /> (Containing my Ajax function)
    <ChildComponent />
        <GrandChildComponent /> (Containing my PopupModal, onSuccess callback)
```

I was calling ajax function of component from grandchild component passing a onSuccess Callback (defined in grandchild component) which was setting state to show popup modal.

I changed it to -

```
<Component /> (Containing my Ajax function, PopupModal)
    <ChildComponent />
        <GrandChildComponent />
```

Instead I called setState (onSuccess Callback) to show popup modal in component (ajax callback) itself and problem solved.

In 2nd case: component was being rendered twice (I had included bundle.js two times in html).

Answer (score 0):

Having named method in place of the anonymous function in `audioNode.addEventListener` 's callback should eliminate the subject warning:

```
    componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState, prevContext) {
    let [audioNode, songLen] = [this.refs.audio, List.length-1];

    audioNode.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        this._endedPlay(songLen, () => {
            this._currSong(this.state.songIndex);
            this._Play(audioNode);
        });
    });

    audioNode.addEventListener('timeupdate', this.callbackMethod );
}

callBackMethod = () => {
    let [remainTime, remainTimeMin, remainTimeSec, remainTimeInfo] = [];

    if(!isNaN(audioNode.duration)) {
        remainTime = audioNode.duration - audioNode.currentTime;
        remainTimeMin = parseInt(remainTime/60);  // 剩余分
        remainTimeSec = parseInt(remainTime%60);  // 剩余秒

        if(remainTimeSec < 10) {
            remainTimeSec = '0'+remainTimeSec;
        }
        remainTimeInfo = remainTimeMin + ':' + remainTimeSec;
        this.setState({'time': remainTimeInfo});
    }
}
```

And yes, named method is needed anyways because `removeEventListener` won't work with anonymous callbacks, as mentioned above several times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cancel all async operation in `componentWillUnmount`
2. Check component is already unmounted when async call `setState`,
   since isMounted flag is deprecated