# when route changes in my React app I clearInterval() and app breaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, react-router-dom

I'm working on a **React app** with **React-router-dom**.

I have a menu with some  react-router-dom's `<NavLink />`, each one takes me to a different route.

In my main route `path="/"` I have ***chartComponent*** with a chart that keeps on changing with random data, like this: `this.chartChangeId = setInterval(()=> this.setState(data), 1500)`.

before I added this:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.chartChangeId);
}
```

To ***chartComponent*** my app didn't break, but I got this error:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>   Please check the code for the BrainWaveChart component.

so I added this to the life cycle.

**But now**, when I click on one of the `<NavLink />` to go to a different route my app breaks, and I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: timeout.close is not a function
>       at exports.clearTimeout.exports.clearInterval (main.js:14)
>       at BrainWaveChart.componentWillUnmount (brainwaveChart.jsx:116)
>       at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:45235)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:37015)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:37054)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:36911)
>       at safelyCallComponentWillUnmount (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:45242)
>       at commitUnmount (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:45368)
>       at commitNestedUnmounts (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:45404)
>       at unmountHostComponents (vendor_f02cab182c1842c98837.js:45687)

Am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`()=> this.setState(data)` is executing even if you clear interval because its already in memory and its in async stack. What you need to do is check if the component exists and only then update state. The simplest thing what to do is

```
const {clearInterval, setInterval} = window;
class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mounted = false;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(this.mounted) this.setState();
    })
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```

However this is more of antipatern. Proper way would be not to use setState in Ajax at all. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE probably imported `{ clearInterval }` automatically for you,
and that's what causing the problem.
Please check if you have `import { clearInterval } from ....` statement in your file,
and remove it.
It happens in some IDE's.
More info available in this link:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12400

Comment: @AjayGupta, if you have read the thread in the link that I shared you would understand that this is an IDE specific issue and not a framework issue.