# React Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components that I route between them by using the Route component from react router dom. One of the component get data from a dummy API server on `componentDidMount` event (using axios package), here is the code:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/posts')
        .then(response => {
            const posts = response.data.slice(0, 4);
            const updatedPost = posts.map(post => {
                return {
                    ...post,
                    author: 'Max'
                };
            });
            this.setState({ posts: updatedPost });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

The bug is, when I redirect from one component to another too fast, or something even not so fast, I get this warning on the console:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

> Please check the code for the Posts component.

What can I do to solve this issue?
I tried to figure out by:
[setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544314/setstate-can-only-update-a-mounted-or-mounting-component-this-usually-mea)
but I didn't really understand when to pass a ref and how. If anyone can give an example how this issue can be solved, it would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reacts warning is valid. How should react *react* when you call `setState` on a component that has already `unmounted`. The right way to handle it would be to `cancel` the data fetching request if the component will be `unmounted` for some reason (like user navigating away).

Below is an advice from the official [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data). make use of the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    externalData: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._asyncRequest = asyncLoadData().then(
      externalData => {
        this._asyncRequest = null;
        this.setState({externalData});
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this._asyncRequest) {
      this._asyncRequest.cancel();
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.externalData === null) {
      // Render loading state ...
    } else {
      // Render real UI ...
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like Axios [supports](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) "cancellable" requests.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by dubes's answer! Thanks a lot, here is my code and it works great!

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

class Posts extends Component {

    asyncRequest = null;
    state = {
        posts: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.asyncRequest = axios.get('/posts', {
            cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
                // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
                cancel = c;
            })
        })
            .then(response => {
                const posts = response.data.slice(0, 4);
                const updatedPost = posts.map(post => {
                    return {
                        ...post,
                        author: 'Max'
                    };
                });
                this.setState({ posts: updatedPost });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.asyncRequest) {
            cancel();
        }
    }
}
```