# React Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have 2 components:
Orders - fetch some data and display it.
ErrorHandler - In case some error happen on the server, a modal will show and display a message.
The ErrorHandler component is warping the order component

I'm using the axios package to load the data in the Orders component, and I use axios interceptors to setState about the error, and eject once the component unmounted.

When I navigate to the orders components back and forward i sometimes get an error in the console:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Orders (at ErrorHandler.jsx:40)
    in Auxiliary (at ErrorHandler.jsx:34)
    in _class2 (created by Route)
```

I tried to solve it by my previous case [React Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591743/react-warning-can-only-update-a-mounted-or-mounting-component) but here I can't make an axios token by the inspectors. Has anyone solved this issue before?

Here are my components:
 
Orders:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../../api/api';
import Order from '../../components/Order/Order/Order';
import ErrorHandler from '../../hoc/ErrorHandler/ErrorHandler';

class Orders extends Component {
    state = {
        orders: [],
        loading: true
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        api.get('/orders.json')
            .then(response => {
                const fetchedOrders = [];
                if (response && response.data) {
                    for (let key in response.data) {
                        fetchedOrders.push({
                            id: key,
                            ...response.data[key]
                        });
                    }
                }
                this.setState({ loading: false, orders: fetchedOrders });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ loading: false });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.orders.map(order => {
                    return (<Order
                        key={order.id}
                        ingrediencies={order.ingrediencies}
                        price={order.price} />);
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ErrorHandler(Orders, api);
```

ErrorHandler:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Auxiliary from '../Auxiliary/Auxiliary';
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';

const ErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, api) => {
    return class extends Component {
        requestInterceptors = null;
        responseInterceptors = null;
        state = {
            error: null
        };

        componentWillMount() {
            this.requestInterceptors = api.interceptors.request.use(request => {
                this.setState({ error: null });
                return request;
            });
            this.responseInterceptors = api.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
                this.setState({ error: error });
            });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            api.interceptors.request.eject(this.requestInterceptors);
            api.interceptors.response.eject(this.responseInterceptors);
        }

        errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
            this.setState({ error: null });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Auxiliary>
                    <Modal
                        show={this.state.error}
                        modalClosed={this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
                        {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                    </Modal>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </Auxiliary>
            );
        }
    };
};

export default ErrorHandler;
```

Comment: use componentDidMount

Comment: Didn't help..still get the error sometimes... :(

Comment: Create a React jsFiddle, it's strange that the same error is shown on componentDidMount

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that's due to asynchronous call which triggers the setState, it can happen even when the component isn't mounted. To prevent this from happening you can use some kind of flags :

```
  state = {
    isMounted: false
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({isMounted: true})
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
      this.state.isMounted = false
  }
```

And later wrap your setState calls with if:

```
if (this.state.isMounted) {
   this.setState({ loading: false, orders: fetchedOrders });
}
```

Edit - adding functional component example:

```
function Component() {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
    return () => {
      setIsMounted(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: From react docs: You should not call setState() in componentWillUnmount() because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

Comment: Right, missed that ... I've updated the dummy example

Comment: Wouldn't this just get rid of the error by not making the state being set and therefore breaking the intended functionality?

Comment: Intended functionality is meant for mounted components only. If a component isn't mounted, then there is no intended functionality. Actually in that case the only solution that is viable is the one presented here.

Comment: @Goran.it What about for a functional component?

Answer (score 4):

You can't set state in componentWillMount method. Try to reconsider your application logic and move it into another lifecycle method.

Comment: I'm not setting the state there, i just make a setup function that will set the state, but it happen after. But i also tried to change it to componentDidMount and the error still exists.

Comment: Look at your ErrorHandler. You do set state there. And the error stack trace tells you this:

Answer (score 0):

I think rootcause is the same as what I answered yesterday, you need to "cancel" the request on `unmount`, I do not see if you are doing it for the `api.get()` call in `Orders` component.

A note on the Error Handling, It looks overly complicated, I would definitely encourage looking at [ErrorBoundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) provided by React. There is no need for you to have `interceptors` or a higher order component.

For ErrorBoundaries, React introduced a lifecycle method called: `componentDidCatch`. 
You can use it to simplify your `ErrorHandler` code to:

```
class ErrorHandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true, errorMessage : error.message });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <Modal 
                    modalClosed={() => console.log('What do you want user to do? Retry or go back? Use appropriate method logic as per your need.')}>
                    {this.state.errorMessage ? this.state.errorMessage : null}
                </Modal>
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Then in your `Orders` Component:

```
class Orders extends Component {
    let cancel;
    state = {
        orders: [],
        loading: true
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.asyncRequest = api.get('/orders.json', {
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
            // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
            cancel = c;
            })
        })
            .then(response => {
                const fetchedOrders = [];
                if (response && response.data) {
                    for (let key in response.data) {
                        fetchedOrders.push({
                            id: key,
                            ...response.data[key]
                        });
                    }
                }
                this.setState({ loading: false, orders: fetchedOrders });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                // please check the syntax, I don't remember if it is throw or throw new
                throw error;
            });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
       if (this.asyncRequest) {
          cancel();
       }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.orders.map(order => {
                    return (<Order
                        key={order.id}
                        ingrediencies={order.ingrediencies}
                        price={order.price} />);
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And use it in your code as:

```
<ErrorHandler>
   <Orders />
</ErrorHandler>
```