# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When fetching data I'm getting:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

The app still works, but react is suggesting I might be causing a memory leak.

I've searched a lot for a solution to this warning and made many changes (including using an isMounted state and an abortController) but haven't found anything which fixes this for me as of yet. This is due to the fact that I want to the output of the API to be a variable or constant so that I can use it in another class.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://jirareportsforsolutions.azurewebsites.net/boards")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    (result) => this.setState(boards = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2).slice(82, -1)))
  )
  // console.log(boards)
}
```

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.selectValues.length > 0) 
    fetch("https://jirareportsforsolutions.azurewebsites.net/sprints/" + boardId)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
      (result) => this.setState(sprints = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2).slice(68, -1)))
    )
    // console.log(sprints)
  }
}
```

This is the render component where 'boards' is being used within a dropdown (using the react-dropdown-select package) and 'sprints' is being passed to a different class(StartSprintDropdown):

```
render() {
  if (boards == null) {
    noData = "No boards available"
  } 
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="boardDropdown">
        <StyledSelect
          placeholder="Select a board"
          color={this.state.color}
          searchBy={this.state.searchBy}
          clearable={this.state.clearable}
          searchable={this.state.searchable}
          dropdownHandle={this.state.handle}
          dropdownHeight={this.state.dropdownHeight}
          direction={this.state.direction}
          labelField={this.state.labelField}
          valueField={this.state.valueField}
          options={boards}
          dropdownGap={this.state.gap}
          keepSelectedInList={this.state.keepSelectedInList}
          onChange={values => this.setValues(values)}
          noDataLabel={noData}
          closeOnSelect={this.state.closeOnSelect}
          dropdownPosition={this.state.dropdownPosition}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <StartSprintDropdown sprints={sprints} boardId={boardId} projectId={projectId} sprintError={sprintError}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );}
}
```

This is the full warning that is shown:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is >a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all >subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

I'm not sure if I have assigned the 'boards' and 'sprints variables correctly as they are not states but the app works fine, although the second fetch (within the componentDidUpdate) constantly fetches once triggered.

Since I'm new to React any help with this and my code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031156/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because somewhere along the line, your component is getting destroyed, then the async call to this.setState gets run and prints this error message.

Try adding this to your class to see if your component is being destroyed too early:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log('unmounting!!!!')
}
```

Comment: The console log shows up instantly, how would I fix this?

Comment: thats a wider question which would require a look at more of your app code - but at least you know the cause...

Comment: perhaps you could post the code which is rendering your component e.g. {somebizarrecondition && <mycomponent /> }

Comment: I have edited the post to show the render component

Comment: Ok but what is the component which your componentdidmount function belongs to?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are asking for, the componentDidMount component is only called after render and is not called anywhere else

Comment: What is the name of the component which owns the componentdidmount function you posted?

Comment: This might help also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498756/when-does-a-component-unmount

Comment: Thanks for the link the componentDidMount is within a class called BoardDropdown. Do you think the problem is something to do with using different classes and destroying DOM nodes?

Comment: No worries - the problem is very likely around 'destroying DOM nodes'. I cannot be more specific without seeing the relevant code. Best to create a new question with these details if still unsure.