# Fix "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The code below gives a console error when I try to push to a new page in my web application:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
>   cleanup function.
>       in PasswordResetPage (created by Context.Consumer)

You will have noticed in the code that is commented out that I've tried to use `useEffect` as this is what most stackoverflow answers points to. However, the error is still present. How can I use `history.push` in this context and get rid of the error?

```
import React, { useState /* , useEffect */ } from 'react'
import useForm from 'react-hook-form'
import Logo from '../assets/images/logo-icon-orange.png'
import TextInput from '../components/TextInput'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import AnimatedButton from '../components/AnimatedButton'
import logger from '../logger'
import { sleep } from '../utils/promise'
import PasswordResetSchema from './validation/PasswordResetSchema'

const PasswordResetPage = ({ history }) => {
  const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)
  // const [isDone, setDone] = useState(false)
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    validationSchema: PasswordResetSchema,
  })

  const onSubmit = async data => {
    setSubmitting(true)
    await sleep(2000)
    logger.info('form data', data)
    // setDone(true)
    history.push('/confirmation')
  }

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (isDone) {
  //     history.push('/confirmation')
  //   }
  // })


  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
      <div className="text-center mb-4">
        <img className="mb-4" src={Logo} alt="Striver" width={72} />
        <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Password reset</h1>
        <p>Enter your email address below and we will send you instructions on how you can reset your password.</p>
      </div>

      <div className="form-label-group">
        <TextInput type="email" id="email" register={register} label="Email address" errors={errors} />
      </div>

      <AnimatedButton actionTitle="Next" isSubmitting={isSubmitting} />
      <Footer />
    </form>
  )
}

export default PasswordResetPage
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031156/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if that works for you:

Code SandBox with working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouteranswerso-817bp

```
const onSubmit = async data => {
    setSubmitting(true)
    await sleep(2000)
    logger.info('form data', data)
    setDone(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDone) {
      history.push('/confirmation')
    }
  },[isDone]);
```

Working code on CodeSandbox:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  function doLogin() {
    console.log("Inside do login...");
    setUser("someUserID");
  }

  function doLogout() {
    console.log("Inside do logout...");
    setUser(null);
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <AllRoutes user={user} doLogin={doLogin} doLogout={doLogout} />
    </Router>
  );
}

function AllRoutes(props) {
  console.log("Rendergin AllRoutes...");
  // console.log(props);
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Component1} />
      <Route exact path="/comp2" component={Component2} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function Component1(props) {
  const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDone) {
      props.history.push("/comp2");
    }
  }, [isDone, props.history]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Component1</div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsDone(true)}>Submit</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component2(props) {
  const [goBack, setGoBack] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (goBack) {
      props.history.push("/");
    }
  }, [goBack, props.history]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Component2</div>
      <button onClick={() => setGoBack(true)}>Go Back</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer because of completeness, however, the root cause was in the form library I'm using. Cheers!

Comment: @AndreGallo I'm using react-hook-form as well and getting this issue with a reset. How did you resolve?

Comment: @Shay I updated to the latest version at that point in time

Comment: @AndreGallo Thanks, that didn't resolve it for me. But at least that's eliminated one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `await sleep(2000)` is a replacement for actual API call.
API calls as well as `history.push` are side effects thus should be places in `useEffect`.
Try this:

```js
const PasswordResetPage = ({ history }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(null);

  // ...

  const onSubmit = async data => {
    setFormData(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    logger.info('form data', formData);
    sleep(2000).then(() => history.push('/confirmation'););
  }, [formData]);

  // ...
}
```