# How to update state in componentWillMount and use that value in the render function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am collecting images from a dispatch call made to an action and mapping the returned response (images) into an array.  When the data is finally returned I am storing this map by setting the state of the imgArray property.  Unfortunately, when I do this I get a warning 'Can only update a mounted or mounting component' and my imgArray property on state is not available or updated in the render function (thus no images are being displaced).  How can I get rid of this warning and get my data to the render function by first storing the data in the state?

componentWillMount function:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(handleLoadProduct(this.props.product.id)).then((data) => {
        let images = data.response.images.map(img => {
            return 'https://b2b.martinsmart.com/productimages/' + img.original;
        });

        this.setState({imgArray: images});    
    });
}
```

Even though the isLoading property is getting set to true in the reducer it still shows up as false here and then the render is getting called before all the data is loaded.

render function:

```
render() {
    const {isLoading, product} = this.props.products;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loader isVisible={true}/>;
    }

    return (
        <View ref={(pc) => this.productCard = pc} style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#D6D6D6'}}>
            <Header/>
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <View style={{height: '100%', borderRadius: 7}}>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        {this.state.imgArray &&
                            <Animated.Image
                                {...this.imgPanResponder.panHandlers}
                                key={'image' + this.state.imgIndex}
                                source={{uri: this.state.imgArray[this.state.imgIndex]}}
                                style={{left: this.imgXPos, width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
                                resizeMethod={'resize'}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                            />
                        }
```

here I uploaded a video demonstrating this:  https://youtu.be/tAbaq2IS4vY

Here is my reducer case:

```
    case types.HANDLE_LOAD_PRODUCT: {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
            product:{}
        };
    }
```

Here is my action function:

```
export function handleLoadProduct(productId) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        if (getState().app.hasNetworkConnection) {
            dispatch({
                type: types.HANDLE_LOAD_PRODUCT
            });

            return API.getProduct(productId).then((response) => {
                return dispatch({
                    type: types.HANDLE_LOAD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
                    response
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Here is how I connect my products from the reducer:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {products} = state;
    return {
        products
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductCard);
```

Comment: First, use *componentDidMount* for doing API calls, not *componentWillMount*. I want to help you, but I need a bit more info: 1. What is the default state of the `this.props.products`? 2. Do you `connect` your component to the `products` from the redux store as `this.props.products`? Please share the code there as well.

Comment: Hi Kaloyan and thanks for wanting to help as I'm pretty suck here!  I edited my question to include the reducer case, action function, and the connect.  The default state of the this.props.products is an object.  I switched to componentDidMount() and that fixed the issue of the images not showing up! So thx for that =]  I'm gonna try to use refs to see if I can get rid of that warning tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the images not showing up issue, switch from `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`. In general, use `componentDidMount` for doing API calls.

The warning, however, might be due to many reasons. Try to [use refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969739/1333836). If you are switching between screens, that might cause the issue too!

Check also the [isMounted post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) in the React docs. I guess the component simply unmounts and then the state changes. Try to play around with `console.log()`s on `componentWillUnmount()` and figure out if the component unmounts before the `this.setState()` is called to change the state. A lot is going on in your code example, that's why it's a bit hard to say exactly what is causing the warning to show up. But these should give you a good clue.

Comment: I wrapped my this.setState call in if (this.refs.productCard) but this.refs is always just an empty object.  Never contains any refs even though I created one on the outer view.  Do you know why this might be??

Comment: Which version of ReactJS are you using? In the current version, 16, creating refs have changed a bit. Please see: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs and try the `React.createRef()` way instead.

Comment: Thanks I am going to create a new question to address the ref issue.